# TikZ takes two pages to display empty output

Tags: tikz-pgf

The simple .tex file below produces a three-page PDF with TexShop (I'm using the latest version on my Mac), the two first of which are blank and the third contains the "Normal text here" part.

What did I do wrong ? Why does TexShop need two pages to display such a small TikZ picture, and why does it fail to display it correctly ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newdimen\myUnit

\setlength{\myUnit}{1cm}


\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xOne}{\myUnit}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xTwo}{2*\myUnit}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\xThree}{\myUnit}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yOne}{2*\myUnit}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yTwo}{\myUnit}% 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\yThree}{\myUnit}%
  \useasboundingbox (0,0) (\xOne+\xTwo+\xThree,\yOne+\yTwo+\yThree);
 \path[draw=cyan] (0,0)
 -- ++(\xOne,\yOne)
 -- ++(\xTwo,\yTwo)
 -- ++(\xThree,-\yThree) 
 -- ++(\xThree,\yThree) 
 -- ++(\xTwo,-\yTwo)
 -- ++(\xOne,\yOne)
 -- cycle
 ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  Normal text here
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tikzpicture` actually becomes rather huge, so it doesn't fit in the first page, and then LaTeX gives up and places it on the second page. To see that it becomes somewhat large, add `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}`, and add `[show background rectangle]` right after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

To understand why things fail, note that lengths are stored as *points*, and 1cm is about 28.45 points. Because of this, `\xOne`, `\xTwo` etc. are nearly thirty times what you intended, consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,array}
\newdimen\myUnit
\setlength{\myUnit}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xOne}{\myUnit}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xTwo}{2*\myUnit}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xThree}{\myUnit}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yOne}{2*\myUnit}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yTwo}{\myUnit}% 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yThree}{\myUnit}%   

\begin{tabular}{>{\ttfamily}ll}
myUnit & \the\myUnit \\
xOne & \xOne \\
xTwo & \xTwo \\
xThree & \xThree \\
yOne & \yOne \\
yTwo & \yTwo \\
yThree & \yThree    
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives this output:

[image]

To get around this issue you can use `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` instead, see example below, or you could use `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myUnit}{1}` instead of a length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newdimen\myUnit
\setlength{\myUnit}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xOne}{\myUnit}% 
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xTwo}{2*\myUnit}% 
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\xThree}{\myUnit}%
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\yOne}{2*\myUnit}% 
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\yTwo}{\myUnit}% 
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\yThree}{\myUnit}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0)  (\xOne+\xTwo+\xThree,\yOne+\yTwo+\yThree);
 \path[draw=cyan] (0,0)
 -- ++(\xOne,\yOne)
 -- ++(\xTwo,\yTwo)
 -- ++(\xThree,-\yThree) 
 -- ++(\xThree,\yThree) 
 -- ++(\xTwo,-\yTwo)
 -- ++(\xOne,\yOne)
 -- cycle
 ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  Normal text here
\end{document}
```

[image]